# Скачать с Google Cloud Storage PHP

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud

```
$analytics = new \Google_Service_Storage($client); 
$objects=$analytics->objects->listObjects({BUCKET});
$object=$analytics->objects->get({BUCKET},$objects->items[0]->name);
```

Получаю объект, ссылку на файл, но не понимаю как скачать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$analytics = new \Google_Service_Storage($client); 
$name={OBJECT_NAME};
$bucket={BUCKET};
$file = $analytics->objects->get($bucket, $name, ['alt' => 'media']);
file_put_contents(basename($name), $file->getBody());
```

решение было следующее

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init($object);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$fh = fopen("file_name.ext", 'w');
fwrite($fh, $output);
fclose($fh);
```

или

```
$url = $object; //Взять url из объекта - в предыдущем тоже также надо
file_put_contents('file_name.ext', file_get_contents($url));
```

Comment: Да, так я пробовал. Проблема что при таких методах скачивания файла, запрос получается не авторизованный и файл соответственно не отдается. В ответ приходит "Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.get access to {название_пакета}"

Comment: Тогда надо вытянуть заголовки авторизации из этого объекта, если это возможно